# Does Kleiman's Theorem work on quasi-projective varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be a projective variety and let $C_1,\ldots,C_n\subseteq X$ be some integral curves contained in $X$. Let $D$ be a divisor such that $D.C\geq 0$ for all curves $C\notin\{C_1,\ldots,C_n\}$. Then is it true that $D^d.V\geq 0$ for all $d$-dimensional integral subvarieties $V\subseteq X$ such that $V\not\subseteq C_1\cup\cdots\cup C_n$?

This seems to be pretty much equivalent to Kleiman's theorem for quasi-projective varieties. However, I have no idea whether it holds or not. How could one proceed?

Comment: If $X$ is strictly quasiprojective, replace it with some compactification and apply Kleiman there (this is sloppy but I think it works). In general, I would expect that if you have $X$ projective and some sort of positivity result (i.e. some intersection is $>0$), in the quasiprojective case you can only expect non-negativity (i.e. some intersection is $\geq 0$). Since this inequality is already weak, nothing should change in the quasiprojective case.

Comment: @TabesBridges But compactifying could violate nefness, couldn't it? Take $Y$ quasi-projective, such that we have integral curves $C,D\subseteq Y$ with $(C+D).C<0$ and $(C+D).D\geq 0$. Then on $X=Y\setminus C$, the divisor $(C+D)|_X$ is nef. This is precisely what confuses me. Can you always compactify preserving nefness?

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't parse your condition on $V$ carefully enough; $V$ can have components contained in the union of curves, even if $V$ itself is not contained in that union.